# Randomly slow hard drive transfer rates

Tags: hard-drive

Do randomly dropping HDD transfer rates (down to a few KB/s) mean it's physically damaged?

So far I've done many diagnostics tests and zero fill wiping. What's bizarre is that the HDD has no SMART warnings and bad sectors.

This is a Western Digital 15EADS. Here are some tests:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't use this tool, so maybe I'm reading this wrong, but these results don't look that strange to me.  What specifically is your concern, am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah the min/max/avg looks good to me...

Comment: Yes, despite this good results hdd transfer is very unstable and it happens while coping files. However each test performed shows good results far beyond reality.

Answer (score 0):

Does the disk behave better when is cold than after heavy use?. It could be an indicator of a semi-defective component in the controller circuit.
I've learned recently (in the hard way) that SMART don't warn you about a failing disk controller.

Comment: There is no difference whenever it's cold or heavily used. This is random and happens very often. You may be right about controller, because surface of the disk looks good to me.